# Can a workstation be added to a domain without granting local administrator rights?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

The question is specifically about whether a domain admin can be restricted by local system security policy.

We've been asked by a client if our closed systems (Windows 10 Pro) can be added to their AD domain while still maintaining the local security policy for those machines. That security policy requires that no one at the client site be able to modify the installed proprietary software and configuration files on those systems.

System administration is not my forte, and I have not been able to find a clear answer to this question after searching this and other sites. TIA

Comment: Seems like it's rather easy to test if you have access to a machine and a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Policies that are applied at the domain level can override local policy. See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374155(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

There is nothing you can do to prevent this by technical means. You may need to consider entering into a contractural agreement with your customer that makes clear what policies they are permitted to apply to this workstation and which they are forbidden to apply.

Comment: Also remember, if anyone has domain admin rights, they literally can alter any configuration in the domain. Even if you "lock them out", they'll just bypass / override your restriction.

Comment: @Lenniey Yep, absolutely.